key error occurs while training YOLO models on Ultralytics with streamlit
Here is the complete code.
import os
import streamlit as st
import torch
import yaml
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Streamlitアプリの設定
st.set_page_config(page_title="YOLO Training App", layout="wide")

# セッションステートの初期化
if "device" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["device"] = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
if "models" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["models"] = [f"yolov{ver}{size}" for ver in ["8", "5"] for size in ["n", "s", "m", "l", "x"]]
if "model" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["model"] = None

# サイドバーの設定
st.sidebar.title("YOLO Training Settings")
model_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select model", st.session_state["models"])
epochs = st.sidebar.number_input("Number of epochs", min_value=1, max_value=200, value=10)
imgz = st.sidebar.number_input("Image size", min_value=32, max_value=1024, value=640)
uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Choose a dataset YAML file", type=["yaml"])

# メインページの設定
st.title("YOLO Training App")
st.write(f"Device: {st.session_state['device']}")

if st.sidebar.button("Load model"):
    try:
        st.session_state["model"] = YOLO(f"{model_name}.yaml")
        model_info = st.session_state["model"].info(verbose=True)
        st.write(f"Model {model_name} loaded.")
        st.write(model_info)
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error loading model: {str(e)}")

if uploaded_file is not None:
    try:
        with open(uploaded_file.name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(uploaded_file.getbuffer())
        st.write(f"Dataset file {uploaded_file.name} uploaded.")

        with open(uploaded_file.name, "r") as f:
            data = yaml.safe_load(f)

        base_path = data.get("path", "")
        train_path = data.get("train", "")
        test_path = data.get("val", "")
        nc = data.get("nc", 0)
        names = data.get("names", [])

        if base_path:
            train_path = os.path.join(base_path, train_path)
            test_path = os.path.join(base_path, test_path)

        st.write(f"Train URL: {train_path}")
        st.write(f"Test URL: {test_path}")
        st.write(f"Number of classes: {nc}")
        st.write(f"Class names: {', '.join(names)}")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error processing dataset file: {str(e)}")

if st.button("Train"):
    if st.session_state["model"] is None:
        st.warning("Please load a model first.")
    elif uploaded_file is None:
        st.warning("Please upload a dataset file first.")
    else:
        try:
            st.write("Training started.")
            st.session_state["model"].train(data=uploaded_file.name, epochs=epochs, imgsz=imgz)
            st.write("Training finished.")
            st.write("Results saved.")
        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f"Error during training: {str(e)}")

The important part is as follows:
if st.button("Train"):
    if st.session_state["model"] is None:
        st.warning("Please load a model first.")
    elif uploaded_file is None:
        st.warning("Please upload a dataset file first.")
    else:
        try:
            st.write("Training started.")
            st.session_state["model"].train(data=uploaded_file.name, epochs=epochs, imgsz=imgz)
            st.write("Training finished.")
            st.write("Results saved.")
        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f"Error during training: {str(e)}")

Pressing the button starts the training, but during the process, an error like "KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "models"'" occurs, even though the code inside the indent, which is supposed to run during training, doesn't explicitly access that part.
2024-04-01 14:05:53.397 WARNING streamlit:
  Warning: to view a Streamlit app on a browser, use Streamlit in a file and
  run it with the following command:

    streamlit run [FILE_NAME] [ARGUMENTS]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 398, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(widget_id, key)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 443, in _getitem
    raise KeyError
KeyError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\yolo2.py", line 23, in <module>
    model_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select model", st.session_state["models"])
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 90, in __getitem__
    return get_session_state()[key]
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\safe_session_state.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    return self._state[key]
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\software_development\python\ImageProcessing\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 400, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(_missing_key_error_message(key))
KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "models". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization'

The warning suggests running with streamlit run, which I am doing. I suspect this error might be specific to Streamlit due to its unique execution form. I've tried fixing the code but to no avail. Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.
Environment: Windows 11, venv virtual environment (Python 3.10.11)
